# C - "incompatible type" warning upon assigning array to pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two lists of words.

My code randomly selects one list, then randomly selects one word in the list.

The code works fine, but I get an `incompatible pointer type` warning.

The problem appears to be with `p = list1`.

However, both `p` and `list1` have a type `char*`, so I don't understand the warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

void test() {

    srand(time(NULL));  // seed the random number generator.

    const char *list1[3] = { "one", "two", "three" }; // first list
    int len1 = 3;

    const char *list2[4] = { "uno", "dos", "tres", "quatro" }; // second list
    int len2 = 4;

    char **p;                  // variable to hold chosen list
    int pcount;                // size of the chosen list
    char word[64] = "none";    // chosen word

    int ran1 = rand() % 2;    // random number 0 or 1

    if (ran1 == 0) { p = list1; pcount = len1; } // warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
    if (ran1 == 1) { p = list2; pcount = len2; } // warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

    strcpy(word, p[rand() % pcount]);
    printf("The word is %s.\n", word);

    return;
}
```

Comment: `char*` and `const char*` are different types.

Comment: This might also help [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)

Comment: just use `const char **p`

Comment: `p` [...]  have a type `char*`: err, what? Please see: `char **p;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `p` should be defined as `const char **p` to be compatible with `const char *list[]`.
- you could initialize the `len1` and `len2` variables to the computed lengths of the arrays to avoid potential discrepancies on larger sets.
- the tests on `ran1` to select the set are both redundant and potentially incomplete. You should make sure all values of `ran1` are covered and let the compiler know. A properly configured compiler with all warnings enabled will complain that `p` and `pcount` are potentially uninitialized.
- you should seed the random number generator just once in your program, otherwise multiple calls to `test()` occurring in the same second will choose the same word.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void test(void) {
    const char *list1[] = { "one", "two", "three" }; // first list
    int len1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);

    const char *list2[] = { "uno", "dos", "tres", "quatro" }; // second list
    int len2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    const char **p;            // variable to hold chosen list
    int pcount;                // size of the chosen list
    char word[64];             // chosen word

    int ran1 = rand() % 2;     // random number 0 or 1

    if (ran1 == 0) {
        p = list1; pcount = len1;
    } else {
        p = list2; pcount = len2;
    }

    strcpy(word, p[rand() % pcount]);
    printf("The word is %s.\n", word);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));  // seed the random number generator.

    test();
    test();
    test();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`list1` is an array of `const char*`.
`p` is a `char**`.

You cannot assign a pointer-to-pointer-to-`const` to a pointer-to-pointer-to-non-`const`.

You need to declare `p` as `const char**`.

---

Go throught [the link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) posted by CannedMoose in comments.
Also, [be careful](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion) when using `const` with double pointer.